# Mac Pro copy paste scrambles what was copied when it is posted a terminal window

Tags: macos, copy, paste, scramble

When I copy some text like `require 'active_record'` from some other window and pasted it into the Mac terminal, it gets re-arranged like `active_supportrequire`. I would like to know how to fix this so that it will paste properly.

Comment: Does this always happen?  Do other programs paste the text correctly?  What program is running in the terminal?

Comment: I can just open terminal session. So far, this is the only place it does not paste correctly. It can happen in the terminal or when running Interactive Ruby (IRB). Have not had a problem pasting anywhere else.